# How can I integrate custom tool of langchain with LLAMA 2

Tags: python, chatbot, huggingface-transformers, langchain, llama

I have create a custom tool for simple calculator in langchain as given in its documentation. I want to use llama 2 for my llm not Openai. but whenever I trying to pass tool to agent using STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION agent, it give me
Could not parse LLM output error and
not able to decide to use my tool for answering. How can I do that ? and is there any other agent which I can use for multi inputs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this issue for longest times.

[Code](https://github.com/pinecone-io/examples/blob/master/learn/generation/llm-field-guide/llama-2/llama-2-70b-chat-agent.ipynb)

[Video](https://youtu.be/6iHVJyX2e50?si=wfNj_uJ8qA9zC5Ey)

Check out the video and the github code. Essentially you need to use a output parser. Because LLAMA 2 outputs text. But you need a json formatted one. Look into these links

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).